# Removing blur from photos

Tags: windows, photography

I have some photos that are a little blurry due to the camera not being held perfectly still.

I'd like some recommendations for Windows software that can remove the blur from the photos and make them look sharper.  I would prefer software that is free.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org) with the sharpen filter. Obviously there are limits to how much can be done with any software - if the shake is too pronounced there is next to no hope.

- Free (Gratis and FLOSS)
- Cross Platform
- Can do a lot more!

Comment: The ``Unsharp Mask`` filter may be more useful in cases of motion blur

Answer (score 1):

Try [SmartDeblur](http://smartdeblur.net/) [Paid software, trial version available]

You can remove Gaussian and Out-of-Focus blur with little tweaking. You can also have it analyze the image and create a custom deconvolution or draw one yourself, which is particularly useful for motion blur.

Drawbacks: It will have hiccups and may crash on small images, this means that it will be hard to use on cropped images. Futhermore, it works better on the photo before doing any other edits on it (in particular if you want to have it analyze it).

I suggest taking the trial version to see if it works for you, and from there decide if you want to purchase.